# cannot update context in react typescript functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context, react-tsx

I'm currently working on using context hook in react typescript and having some trouble with updating and confused about the `.Provider` and `.Comsumer` of the API.

this is my code about increasing 1 day when clicking on the button

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useState} from "react"


type MonthCalendarProps = {

};


const CalendarContext = createContext({
    focusDate: new Date(),
    selectedDate: new Date(),
    changeFocusDate: (date: Date) => {}
})



function IncreaseButton(props : any) {

    const calendarContext = useContext(CalendarContext)

    const increase = () => {
        console.log(props.value.focusDate)
        let tmpDate : Date = calendarContext.focusDate
        tmpDate.setDate(tmpDate.getDate() + 1)
        calendarContext.changeFocusDate(tmpDate)
    }

    const getStringFromDate = (date: Date) : string  => {
        console.log(date)
        return date.toDateString()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{getStringFromDate(calendarContext.focusDate)}</p>
            <button onClick = {increase}>
                +
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default function MonthCalendar ( {} : MonthCalendarProps) {

    const [focusDate, setFocusDate] = useState(new Date())
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date())
    const value = {focusDate: focusDate, selectedDate: selectedDate, changeFocusDate: setFocusDate}

    const context = useContext(CalendarContext)

    console.log(context.focusDate)

    return (
        <CalendarContext.Provider value = {value}>
           <CalendarContext.Consumer>
                {value => <IncreaseButton value = {value}/>}
            </CalendarContext.Consumer>
        </CalendarContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

When clicking the button, the `console.log` inside `increase` function showed that the `focusDate` is updated but the UI ,a.k.a `<p>{getStringFromDate(calendarContext.focusDate}</p>` was not updated.

What's the problem with my code and how to fix it? and can you guys explain **Why**?

If it's possible, can you also explain more about behavior of `.Consumer` and `.Provider` for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let tmpDate : Date = calendarContext.focusDate
tmpDate.setDate(tmpDate.getDate() + 1)
calendarContext.changeFocusDate(tmpDate)
```

You are mutating the existing date object, not creating a new one. When you set state, react will do an `===` between the old and new state. Since they're the same object, it looks like nothing has changed, and so react skips rendering.

Instead, make a new date:

```
let tmpDate = new Date(calendarContext.focusDate);
tmpDate.setDate(tmpDate.getDate() + 1)
calendarContext.changeFocusDate(tmpDate)
```

P.S, in MonthCalendar you're calling `const context = useContext(CalendarContext)`. This will only get the context from *parent* components. It will not get the context from itself. That's not contributing to the bug in IncreaseButton, but it will cause the `console.log(context.focusDate)` to be misleading